# Docker compose nginx get site running from another container

Tags: php, laravel, nginx, docker-compose

I have two containers running, one is running PHP and a laravel site which is all working fine. The second container is an nginx container, currently returning 404 error but I would like to render the site via the PHP container.

```
- app
- bootstrap
- config
- database
- nginx
    - default.conf
    - DockerFile
- php
- public
- resources
- routes
- storage
- vendor
- docker-compose.yml
- docker-production.yml
- DockerFile
```

DockerFile

```
FROM php:7.4

RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y openssl zip unzip git cron
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
RUN apt-get clean && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql

WORKDIR /app
COPY . .

RUN composer install

ADD config/laravel_cron /etc/cron.d/cron
RUN chmod 0644 /etc/cron.d/cron

RUN touch /var/log/cron.log
RUN chmod 0777 /var/log/cron.log

RUN crontab /etc/cron.d/cron
RUN service cron start

RUN echo "Europe/London" > /etc/timezone
RUN dpkg-reconfigure -f noninteractive tzdata

EXPOSE 8000
```

docker-production.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  horse-racing-api:
    container_name: horse_racing_api
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
  web-server:
    container_name: web_server
    ports:
      - 80:80
    build:
      context: nginx
      dockerfile: DockerFile
    depends_on:
      - horse-racing-api
    links:
      - horse-racing-api
    volumes:
      - ./:/app
volumes:
  app:
```

nginx/DockerFile

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ./default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
```

nginx/default.conf

```
server {
    listen 80;
    index index.php index.html;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    root /var/www/public;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass horse-racing-api:8000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        gzip_static on;
    }
}
```

Honestly been piecing this together from resources around the internet :/

Comment: `fastcgi_pass horse-racing-api:8000;` seems to be confusing the CGI network connection with an HTTP network connection – Nginx can talk to PHP-FPM over TCP which is what you're configuring there. It sounds like what you want is Nginx to just be a proxy? Why does this need to be 2 separate containers? (I'd also ask whether it needs to be in a container at all, but that's just my personal biases.)

Comment: @miken32 Thanks for the feedback. This has only been set up as two containers due to the fact that the main container I am using was what I had originally set up and have been working on and have managed to get everything working. I later discovered I need an apache or nginx instance to serve the site on on the web, so started about setting up the second container. Would there be a lot of change needed to get in running in one contaner?

Comment: No idea, I haven’t seen the value of containers. It’s `dnf install nginx` or `apt install nginx` for me.